# How to parse out a grid of numbers in pictorial form?

Tags: ocr

Assuming all the grids can contain any number from 1 to 99 in each, what's the simplest way to recognize each number?

For example:

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|-----------|
|11 | 12| 13|
|-----------|
|4  | 5 | 6 |
|-----------|
```

How do I parse them into a 2 dimensional array? Language doesn't matter, I just want to get a general solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you know that to be the format I would go with either regex or simple string splitting

Examples in perl:

REGEX:

```
my @data;

for( <FILE> ) {
   next unless /\d/;
   /\D*(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D*/;
   $data[$#data + 1] = ( $1, $2, $3 );
}
```

STRING OPS:

```
my @data;
for ( <FILE> ) {
    next unless /\d/;
    $data[$#data + 1] = split /|/, $_;
 }
```

Or something to that effect.